# Check if Webview loaded more than once?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to check that web view is loaded more than once with some other link in single web view widget. Is it possible to find it ??

I done enough search but result not matched to my query and all i found in SO was related to render completed.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it for testing purposes?

Comment: @Anfal No testing purpose. i want to implement it

Comment: First one i want to check web view rendered more than one with another link

Comment: when you override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` you will see         `view.loadUrl(url);` which literally loads the url in string form you provided

Comment: I state the problem clearly. For instance, i loaded some tutorial link via that i go another one. Here i want to find second link

Comment: Ok but you want to find second link to what? your question is too vague.

Comment: I want second link is loaded via first one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the first link is the referrer of the newly loaded second link you can set extra headers via

```
loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> extraHeaders)
```

for example

```
Map<String, String> eH = new HashMap<>();
eh.put("Referrer", currentUrl);
webView.loadUrl(url, eH);
```

then override

```
 shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

method of WebViewClient class and retrieve the headers there you can use

```
request.getRequestHeaders().get("Referrer");
```

to get the referrer of the page.